# Use of <param> in <generator> in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate

The question that I may be asking may be a rather trivial one, but still request someone to explain me the differnce between the following codes:

```
<id name="Key" column="Date_Interval_Key" type="long" >
  <generator class="sequence" >
    <param name="sequence">SEQ_DATE_INTERVAL</param>
  </generator>
</id>
```

and a similar code but where we do not use the param tags. What I cannot seem to understand is that what does SEQ_DATE_INTERVAL refer to? Searching on the internet I found out that:

> If any parameters are required to
>   configure or initialize the generator
>   instance, they are passed using the
>   param element.

But can someone explain me that where is this SEQ_DATE_INTERVAL (or its value) passed from within my code? Is this useful or can I continue without using the  tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `param` is instructing [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/02/09/nh2-1-0-new-generators.aspx) to utilize a (probably) Oracle Sequence to get the `Id` value of the entity. If you don't specify a `param`, NHibernate will use a generic one for it, named `Hibernate_Sequence`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I inferred from your answer is that we can actually skip the mentioning of param in the above sample code and go ahead. Also I was curious whether we can use this param declared here anywhere else in our NHibernate queries ?

Comment: @tahoka You can skip the param, but if you're using Oracle sequences, you'll probably want a sequence for each table / class. And what would you want to do with that param? NHibernate will get the next value of the sequence automatically.